# Как обновить переменную в компоненте из store?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Как обновить переменную в компоненте из store?
в модалке записываю в стор выбранную категорию вот так

```
getCategory(category) {
      this.$store.commit('categories/SELECT_CATEGORY', category)
    },
```

сам store categories.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  categories: [],
  category: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  SELECT_CATEGORY(state, category) {
    state.category = category
  },
}
```

как в другом компоненте обновить переменю category_id в data()

```
data(){
  return{
     category_id: 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `category_id` как [вычисляемое свойство](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), которое будет полагаться на значение из `getters` для `store` (это позволит реактивно обновлять значение переменной при обновлении ее значения в `store`):

```
computed: {
 ...mapGetters(['GET_SELECTED_CATEGORY']),
 category_id(){
   return this.GET_SELECTED_CATEGORY
 }
},
```

В сочетании с [вспомогательной функцией mapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mapgetters) и [вспомогательной функцией
mapMutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/api/#mapmutations) вы можете использовать следующий пример:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: [],
    category: [],
  },
  getters: {
    GET_SELECTED_CATEGORY: (state) => {
      return state.category
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SELECT_CATEGORY(state, category) {
    state.category = category
  },
  },
})

const {
  mapGetters,
  mapMutations
} = Vuex

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['GET_SELECTED_CATEGORY']),
    category_id(){
      return this.GET_SELECTED_CATEGORY
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['SELECT_CATEGORY']),
    getCategory(e) {
      this.SELECT_CATEGORY(e.target.value)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.3.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  category_id = {{ category_id }}
  <hr>
  <select @change="getCategory">
    <option value="category1">category1</option>
    <option value="category2">category2</option>
    <option value="category3">category3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```